# Recovery Mode does not find internal nor external storage

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, storage

Before I had CyanogenMod 9 on my Samsung Galaxy S i9000. Then, suddenly it did not boot anymore and I could not boot into recovery mode neither.

So I flashed different kernels with Odin (speedmod, vodoo) to be able to boot into recovery mode - which worked.

Within the recovery mode (ClockworkMod Recovery v5) I can not access neither my internal storage nor my external SD card.
I just see: unknown volume for path [/cache...]

Also tried the vodoo Kernel with ext4 support (as I assumed CM 9 uses ext4).

Which steeps are necessary to get the phone working again? I can not access any storage at all...

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have valuable data on it or are you OK with just moving forward and get it working again? If you can sacrifice your data just use heimdall and start over: [CM's full update guide for the i9000](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide). CM10 nightlies are here: [i9000](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd) and [i9000 model B](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysbmtd)

Comment: I'm OK with flashing the whole device. The only thing I don't know how to flash the full ROM onto the device without using the RecoveryMode option "install from Zip". I only flashed different kernels onto the device with Odin, but never a full ROM. Does this work too?

Comment: You need heimdall only once to install a custom recovery (see my heimdall vs. odin remark in my comment below TheAndroNerd's answer). Then you boot into this recovery and do all further steps there (backup/restore/install_from_zip/wipe/etc.)

Comment: I actually can access a recovery. But inside the recovery I can not access my memory. so I can not backup/restore/install_from_zip. Probably I need to re-partition while flashing another kernel, but I still don't know where to get the partition information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Odin or Hiemdall (preferred) to flash a new ROM, and or flash a new partition table.

It sounds like the partition's have been erased, and as such should be remade by flashing a new ROM.

Comment: Heimdall is said to be more reliable (use ODIN for factory firmwares from Samsung). Source [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1110927)

Comment: I followed this howto [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1647890) to re-partition and flash a stock ROM. This worked for me.